# WS-I Basic Profile v1.1 confusion

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I am tasked with consuming the following wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
      <s:import />
      <s:element name="Calculate">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="DipApInput" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CalculateResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="DipApOutput" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <s:element name="DipApInput" type="DipApInputType" />
      <s:complexType name="DipApInputType">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="OnderdeelType">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL">
                <s:complexType>
                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_FUNCTIE" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_DATACAT" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_APPUSER" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_APPCODE" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_BRONNM" type="s:string" />
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP">
                <s:complexType>
                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP_INGDAT" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="VZ">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_VOLGNUM" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_GEBDAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_GESLACH" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING_PERC" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL_PERC" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_OORSPR_PENS_DAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_GEWENSTE_PENS_DAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_L_DUUR" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_KPHRKO" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_OWV2005" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_OWN2005" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="OnderdeelType" abstract="true" />
      <s:complexType name="DipApInternInputType">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="OnderdeelType">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL">
                <s:complexType>
                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_FUNCTIE" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_DATACAT" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_APPUSER" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_APPCODE" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_BRONNM" type="s:string" />
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP">
                <s:complexType>
                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP_INGDAT" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="VZ">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_VOLGNUM" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_GEBDAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_GESLACH" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING_PERC" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL_PERC" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_OORSPR_PENS_DAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_GEWENSTE_PENS_DAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_L_DUUR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SWAPCURVE">
                            <s:complexType>
                              <s:sequence>
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IMDBEURZEROS" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IMDBILL" type="s:string" />
                              </s:sequence>
                            </s:complexType>
                          </s:element>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="KVB_TABEL">
                            <s:complexType>
                              <s:sequence>
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_VALIDITY" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_GESLACHT" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_LEEFTIJDVAN" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_LEEFTIJDTOT" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_STIJGINGVAN" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_STIJGINGTOT" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_DUURVAN" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_DUURTOT" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_OPPPRATIOVAN" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_OPPPRATIOTOT" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_AFSLAG" type="s:string" />
                              </s:sequence>
                            </s:complexType>
                          </s:element>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PARAMETERS">
                            <s:complexType>
                              <s:sequence>
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_OfferRisk_4_weeks" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_EK_Percentage" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_EK_Minimum" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_EK_Maximum" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_DK_VAST_JAAR" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_DK_PERCENTAGE" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_DK_MAXIMUM" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_TOTAALKOSTEN_MAXIMUM" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_BEHEERKOSTEN" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_MONTHLYBENEFITSUR" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_OFFERRISK_1_WEEK" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_EK_VAST_BEDRAG" type="s:string" />
                                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PAR_INTLFTVERSCHIL_NS" type="s:string" />
                              </s:sequence>
                            </s:complexType>
                          </s:element>
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_KPHRKO" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_OWV2005" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_OWN2005" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="DipApOutputType">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="OnderdeelType">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL">
                <s:complexType>
                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_VIEWCOD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_FUNCTIE" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_DATACAT" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_APPLNM" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_APPLVS" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AL_BRONNM" type="s:string" />
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XG" type="XGType" />
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP">
                <s:complexType>
                  <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PP_INGDAT" type="s:string" />
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="VZ">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_VOLGNUM" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_GEBDAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="VZ_GESLACH" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING_PERC" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL_PERC" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_OORSPR_PENS_DAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_GEWENSTE_PENS_DAT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_L_DUUR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_VZ_1_LFT_JR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_VZ_1_LFT_MND" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_VZ_2_LFT_JR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_VZ_2_LFT_MND" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_ODPNS_JR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_ODPNS_MND" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_PARTPNS_JR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_PARTPNS_MND" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_ODPNS_HOOG_JR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_ODPNS_HOOG_MND" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_ODPNS_LAAG_JR" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_ODPNS_LAAG_MND" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_KST_TOT" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CAS_IG_PP_KOOPS_NETTO" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR">
                      <s:complexType>
                        <s:sequence>
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_KPHRKO" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_OWV2005" type="s:string" />
                          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PR_OWN2005" type="s:string" />
                        </s:sequence>
                      </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                  </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
              </s:element>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="XGType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XG_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XG_STATUS" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XG_STATUST" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="XM" type="XMType" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="XMType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XM_VRWRKCD" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XM_VOLGNUM" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XM_STATTXT" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XM_XPATH" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="DipApOutput" type="DipApOutputType" />
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="CalculateSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Calculate" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="CalculateSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CalculateResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ColanWebServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="Calculate">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:CalculateSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:CalculateSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ColanWebServiceSoap" type="tns:ColanWebServiceSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Calculate">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/Calculate" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="ColanWebServiceSoap12" type="tns:ColanWebServiceSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Calculate">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/Calculate" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ColanWebService">
    <wsdl:port name="ColanWebServiceSoap" binding="tns:ColanWebServiceSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://nnwebservices-at.colimbra.net/website/nnip/services/dipactiefpensioen/colanwebservice.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ColanWebServiceSoap12" binding="tns:ColanWebServiceSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://nnwebservices-at.colimbra.net/website/nnip/services/dipactiefpensioen/colanwebservice.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I use the microsoft wsdl tool to create a proxy class. However, it gives me this warning:

> Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
>   R2105: All xsd:schema elements contained in a wsdl:types element of a DESCRIPTION MUST have a targetNamespace attribute with a valid and non-null value, UNLESS the xsd:schema element has xsd:import and/or xsd:annotation as its only child element(s).
>     -  schema from service description with targetNamespace='http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/'.

And subsequently, when I use the generated proxy class, the call to the webservice fails. My request is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Calculate xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
      <DipApInput xmlns="">
        <AL>
          <AL_VRWRKCD xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">0</AL_VRWRKCD>
          <AL_FUNCTIE xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">01</AL_FUNCTIE>
          <AL_DATACAT xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">2</AL_DATACAT>
          <AL_APPUSER xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">PN</AL_APPUSER>
          <AL_APPCODE xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">66</AL_APPCODE>
          <AL_BRONNM xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">PN</AL_BRONNM>
        </AL>
        <PP>
          <PP_VRWRKCD xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">0</PP_VRWRKCD>
          <PP_INGDAT xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">20170601</PP_INGDAT>
          <VZ xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
            <VZ_VRWRKCD>0</VZ_VRWRKCD>
            <VZ_VOLGNUM>1</VZ_VOLGNUM>
            <VZ_GEBDAT>19520601</VZ_GEBDAT>
            <VZ_GESLACH>M</VZ_GESLACH>
          </VZ>
          <VZ xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
            <VZ_VRWRKCD>0</VZ_VRWRKCD>
            <VZ_VOLGNUM>2</VZ_VOLGNUM>
            <VZ_GEBDAT>19520601</VZ_GEBDAT>
            <VZ_GESLACH>V</VZ_GESLACH>
          </VZ>
          <CAS xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
            <CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING>N</CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING>
            <CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL>N</CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL>
            <CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG>N</CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG>
            <CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL>N</CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL>
            <CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG>N</CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG>
          </CAS>
          <PR xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
            <PR_VRWRKCD>0</PR_VRWRKCD>
            <PR_KPHRKO/>
            <PR_OWN2005>100.000</PR_OWN2005>
          </PR>
        </PP>
      </DipApInput>
    </Calculate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But the party that provided the webservice claims the request should have been like this (most namespaces stripped):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Calculate xmlns="http://Colan.nnip.service.dipactiefpensioen/">
      <DipApInput xmlns="">
        <AL>
          <AL_VRWRKCD>0</AL_VRWRKCD>
          <AL_FUNCTIE>01</AL_FUNCTIE>
          <AL_DATACAT>2</AL_DATACAT>
          <AL_APPUSER>PN</AL_APPUSER>
          <AL_APPCODE>66</AL_APPCODE>
          <AL_BRONNM>PN</AL_BRONNM>
        </AL>
        <PP>
          <PP_VRWRKCD>0</PP_VRWRKCD>
          <PP_INGDAT>20170601</PP_INGDAT>
          <VZ>
            <VZ_VRWRKCD>0</VZ_VRWRKCD>
            <VZ_VOLGNUM>1</VZ_VOLGNUM>
            <VZ_GEBDAT>19520601</VZ_GEBDAT>
            <VZ_GESLACH>M</VZ_GESLACH>
          </VZ>
          <VZ>
            <VZ_VRWRKCD>0</VZ_VRWRKCD>
            <VZ_VOLGNUM>2</VZ_VOLGNUM>
            <VZ_GEBDAT>19520601</VZ_GEBDAT>
            <VZ_GESLACH>V</VZ_GESLACH>
          </VZ>
          <CAS>
            <CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING>N</CAS_IG_PP_STIJGING>
            <CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL>N</CAS_IG_PP_UITRUIL>
            <CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG>N</CAS_IG_PP_VERVROEG>
            <CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL>N</CAS_IG_PP_UITSTEL>
            <CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG>N</CAS_IG_PP_HOOG_LAAG>
          </CAS>
          <PR>
            <PR_VRWRKCD>0</PR_VRWRKCD>
            <PR_KPHRKO/>
            <PR_OWN2005>100.000</PR_OWN2005>
          </PR>
        </PP>
      </DipApInput>
    </Calculate>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My first reaction was that the party that provided the wsdl should fix it to conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1. However, if I load this wsdl in SoapUI and validate the wsdl it finds no errors.

Now I am wondering if wsdl.exe or SoapUI is right about the validity of this wsdl. And if SoapUI is right, how do I fix my proxy class?

Comment: Moolie, have you tried importing wsdl in soapui? what happens? Alternatively you can validate the wsdl online as well, I believe.

Comment: Rao, I have imported the wsdl in SoapUI, and validated it online. The validators say it's fine.

Comment: Does it mean you call the service from soapUI successfully?

Comment: Yes, I can call the service from soapui successfully

Comment: I have tried creating the proxy class by using 'Add Service Reference' from Visual Studio as well. That uses svcutil.exe under the hood to create the proxy class. Same result though.